# How to get the resourceId of an image in android[kotlin]?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I am trying to create a list view using custom adapter(without view holder).I want to insert an image to my custom list view.

I ended up getting this line of code:

```
class CategoryAdapter(context: Context, categories: List<Category>) : BaseAdapter(){

val context = context
val categories = categories

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val categoryView: View

    categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, null)
    val categoryImage : ImageView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2)
    val categoryName : TextView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)

    val category = categories[position]


    val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier(category.image, "drawable", context.packageName)
    categoryImage.setImageResource(resourceId)
    categoryName.text = category.title

    return categoryView
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    return categories[position]

}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return 0
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return categories.count()
}}
```

This works completely fine. I don't have any clue about how the below line works.

```
  val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier(category.image, "drawable", context.packageName)
```

Can u explain me this code?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use :

**Dynamically Retrieving Resources in Android**

Normally, when retrieving resources **(drawables, strings, what have you)** in code you use the automatically generated R.java to do so. However, I recently in my application wherein item in a ImageView a different icon next to it. The data for all this is stored in drawable as an Image, which meant that there was no way for me to link my data to R.java.
Still, I needed some way to get a hold of the Drawable by name, and so I first turned to `getResources().getIdentifier()`. This method does the job well of finding the resource id of anything you desire, in any package:

Based on this [Blog](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html).

***Like :***

```
if (cnt == 7) {
    cnt = 1;
}
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("ad_banner" + cnt, "drawable", getPackageName());
activityTwillioCallBinding.imgAdView.setImageResource(resID);
cnt++;
```

This is all well and good.

Based on this document https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

**getResources()**

Return a Resources instance for your application's package.

**public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)**

Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and defPackage, respectively, are specified here.

**Note:** use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

**Parameters**

name    String: The name of the desired resource.

defType String: Optional default resource type to find, if "type/" is not included in the name. Can be null to require an explicit type.

defPackage  String: Optional default package to find, if "package:" is not included in the name. Can be null to require an explicit package.

**Returns**
int int The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)